# Finding every third word in a sentence and replacing only its letters with the # symbol

Tags: python, replace

This is my code:

```
def redact_words(sentence):
    redacted_sentence = sentence.split()
    for word in redacted_sentence[2::3]:
        for i in word:
            if i.isalpha():
                word.replace(i, '#')
            else:
                continue
    return " ".join(redacted_sentence)
```

if the input is `sentence = "You cannot drink the word 'water'."`
the output should be `"You cannot ##### the word '#####'."`

The output I get is just a list of the words in my input.

Comment: Use `return " ".join(redacted_sentence)` instead.

Comment: Thanks @MattDMo but that only helps make the output into a sentence instead of a list. The # symbols are still not there.

Comment: @ThaboThandekiso: You forgot to reassign and replace the actual `word`. `word.replace(i, '#')` constructs a replaced string, but leaves the string in `word` unchanged. And even if you changed `word`, it wouldn't change the `str` in `redacted_sentence` at that index.

Comment: @ShadowRanger How can I do it?

Comment: @ThaboThandekiso: I posted [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73449027/364696) with a couple options (one hewing as close as possible to your code, the other optimizing it significantly).

Answer (score 0):

You've got two issues that sum to the same problem: Creating and discarding mutated copies of the string, while leaving the original untouched. `str.replace` must be assigned somewhere to be useful (usually reassigning `word` in this case), but also, to update the original `list`, you must reassign that index in the `list` (`word` is a separate alias to the object in the `list`, but reassigning word just rebinds `word` and breaks the aliasing, it doesn't change the contents of the `list`). So the solution is:

1. Keep the results from each `replace` operation
2. Put the final result back into the `list` at the same location

The minimalist modification to your code that achieves this result while still following the same basic design is:

```
from itertools import count  # So we can track the index to perform replacement at

def redact_words(sentence):
    redacted_sentence = sentence.split()
    for i, word in zip(count(2, 3), redacted_sentence[2::3]):  # Track index and value
        for c in set(word):  # Change name to c; i is for indices, not characters/letters
                             # For minor efficiency gain, dedupe word so we don't replace same char over and over
            if c.isalpha():
                word = word.replace(c, '#')  # Reassign back to word so change not lost
        redacted_sentence[i] = word  # Replace original word in list with altered word
    return " ".join(redacted_sentence)
```

A faster solution would replace the inner loop with a single-pass regex substitution or (if only ASCII need be handled) `str.translate` call, replacing `O(n²)` work per word with `O(n)` work, e.g.:

```
import re
from itertools import count  # So we can track the index to perform replacement at

# Precompile regex that matches only alphabetic characters and bind its sub method
# while we're at it    
replace_alpha = re.compile(r'[^\W\d_]').sub

def redact_words(sentence):
    redacted_sentence = sentence.split()
    for i, word in zip(count(2, 3), redacted_sentence[2::3]):  # Track index and value
        # Replace every alphabetic character with # in provided word and replace
        # list's contents at same index
        redacted_sentence[i] = replace_alpha('#', word)
    return " ".join(redacted_sentence)
```

Comment: I have never used itertools before. This just opened up my thinking of looping. Thank you

Comment: @ThaboThandekiso: Yeah, the `itertools` module has a *ton* of useful features in it. In this case, it's basically just using `itertools.count`+`zip` to handle the fact that `enumerate` doesn't allow you to use a custom `step` along with the custom `start`, so it's not that impressive, but `itertools` offers a *lot* more than that. If you learn it well, then along with `enumerate` and `zip` (and using list comprehensions over loops in some cases) you basically never need to write an unPythonic `for i in range(len(someseq)):` style loop.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a way you can do it.

```
def redact_words(sentence, red_acted_words=None):
    if red_acted_words is None:
        red_acted_words = sentence.split()[2::3]
    for  rword in red_acted_words:
        nword = ""
        for c in rword:
            if c.isalpha():
                nword = nword + c
        j = "#" * len(nword)
        sentence = sentence.split(nword)
        sentence = j.join(sentence)
    return sentence

redact_words("You cannot drink the word 'water'.", red_acted_words=["water", "drink"])
redact_words("You cannot drink the word 'water'.")
```

```
def redact_words(sentence):
    red_acted_words = sentence.split()[2::3]
    for rword in red_acted_words:
        nword = ""
        for c in rword:
            if c.isalpha():
                nword = nword + c
        j = "#" * len(nword)
        sentence = sentence.split(nword)
        sentence = j.join(sentence)
    return sentence

redact_words("You cannot drink the word 'water'.")
```

Comment: The redacted words are supposed to be detected automatically - every third word.

Comment: @MattDMo okay - try the new function.

Comment: It doesn't work when there are repeated words in the sentence. Try `"This is a a sentence sentence with repeated repeated words in the sentence."` This is because you're using `list.index(word)`, which only returns the *first occurrence* of an entry in a list.

Comment: @MattDMo fair point... but you could easily just "detect" them like in my first function. Your first comment literally doesn't make any sense, given passing sentence.split()[2::3] as a kwarg would handle it the exact same as it would after I changed my code.

Answer (score -1):

We can accomplish this with a little Python magic:

```
def redact_words(sentence):
    redacted_sentence = []
    sentence = sentence.split()
    for pos, word in enumerate(sentence, start=1):
        if pos % 3 == 0:
            word = "".join("#" if letter.isalpha() else letter for letter in word)
        redacted_sentence.append(word)
    return " ".join(redacted_sentence)
```

First, we create a list to contain the words of the new sentence. Next, after splitting the sentence into a list, we use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to generate the positions of each word in the sentence, along with the word itself. By starting at 1, we can use the modulus operator to see if the position is evenly divisible by 3. If so, we use a comprehension to replace all the alphabetical characters in `word` with `#`, leaving the other characters alone, then reassign the results back to `word`. Finally, we append the word to the `redacted_sentence` list, regardless of whether it's been changed, and return a string with all the words joined together with a space.

Comment: Thank you. This makes complete sense to my novice coding brain

Comment: @ThaboThandekiso that's what I was aiming for.